# How to use innerHTML in typescript code with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

How to use innerHTML from typescript code with Angular 2 RC4?
I have this problem: when an user click one specific button I want to add some precompiled html code. For example:

Typescript code

```
private addHTML() {
    // the html go there I suppose, I don't know how to implement this part
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="exampleSelect1" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">My HTML code</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addHTML">ADD</button>
</div>
<hr>
```

Or maybe this is a wrong way. Let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
htmlYouWantToAdd;

private addHTML() {
    this.htmlYouWantToAdd = "<b>Some HTML you want to display</b>";
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="exampleSelect1" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">My HTML code</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addHTML()">ADD</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div *ngIf="htmlYouWantToAdd" [innerHTML]="htmlYouWantToAdd"></div>
```

Comment: This method work but only once. If I click a second or third time it doesn't add the html. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DanielZarioiu What do you mean? I just tested it - created a method that sets `htmlYouWantToAdd` to null, and after I call `addHTML` again, it works.

Comment: Ok, there was something wrong with my code. Thanks for your solution it work very well!!